# Default route configuration on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, routes

I have an android computer from a vending machine and try to change the default route on it. I use this command:

```
ip route change default via 10.1.1.1
```

But after every reboot the route changes. How can I change the route and be sure it saves? Is there any autoboot config files that can change it? 
Android version is 4.4.2.